# What is wrong with the logic i used in my python program for the question described below?

Tags: python

> Two strings are given. Modify 1st string such that all the common characters of the 2nd strings have to be removed and the uncommon characters of the 2nd string have to be concatenated with uncommon characters of the 1st string.

My code for the above question is:

```
str_1=input('Enter string 1') 
str_2=input('Enter string 2')

len_1=len(str_1)
len_2=len(str_2)

status=0

str_3=' '

for i in range(0,len_1):
   for j in range(0,len_2):
       if(str_1[i]==str_2[j]):
          status=1
          break

   if(status==0):
       str_3=str_3+str_1[i]

for i in range(0,len_2):
   for j in range(0,len_1):
        if(str_2[i]==str_1[j]):
           status=1
           break

   if(status==0):
        str_3=str_3+str_2[i]  

print('The formatted string is',str_3)
```

I'm not getting the desired output. Please help me with this.

An example of input and output for the question is:-

```
Input:
  aabcd
  gafd
Output:
 bcgf
```

Comment: What output _are_ you getting and what exactly are you not understanding about it?

Comment: ('The formatted string is', ' ') This is the output that i get when i run this code in rextester

Comment: Which version of python are you using and what version is rextester using?

Comment: 'python 2.7.12' This is the version used

Comment: does the output have to be in order as shown?

Comment: Yes,it is to be in the order as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing too make too complex here just loop through the items of first, check if they are not in the second string, if not keep them. Then loop through s2, if there are not in s1, append them.

```
s1 = 'aabcd'
s2 = 'gafd'

res = [i for i in s1 if i not in s2]
for i in s2:
    if i not in s1:
        res.append(i)

print(''.join(str(i) for i in res))
# bcgf
```

If the order of the elements in the output is not important

```
i = set(s1) ^ set(s2)
print(''.join(str(x) for x in i))
# gbcf
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @KrishnaKanna If this solved your problem would appreciate if you checked solved thanks cheers!